# Main.storyboardc could not be opened. Interface Builder cannot open compiled nibs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, interface-builder

I've got library from another team that contains `framework` and `bundle` file.
While I was trying to go through library I found issue with `Main.storyboardc` file.

**It states the document "Main.storyboardc" could not be opened. Interface Builder cannot open compiled nibs.**

[image: Screenshot]

What does `.storyboardc` file mean? **Is it human error of adding 'c' to storyboard file?**

If no then what is the fix?

I'm trying to read content of .storyboardc file but getting an error of permission.

Can this permission be by-passed? How to set such permission to storyboard file?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: see this once https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16241

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik : That was really helpful but didn't solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

A `.storyboardc` file is a compiled storyboard, meaning it's just the 1s and 0s, not the actual XML that you work with using Interface Builder. If you open this up with a text editor like Sublime Text, you'll see this:

[image: Compiled Storyboard]

You can attempt to decompile the binary but I've tried and failed doing so on my own project. That's not to say it's not possible if you find the right tool to do so. I can tell you that neither [Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com) nor the free version of [IDA Pro](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) seem to give usable information. There may be others out there but those were the ones I tried.

To actually answer your question, I think you need to go back to the team that gave it to you. As stated in the comments of the OP, it's possible that they were using an older version of Xcode but my guess is that they pulled the export from some kind of build or cache folder, not the actual repo.